# Is it possible to add visual padding around a character?

Tags: faces, text-properties, display

Is it possible to add visual padding around a variable width character (generally too, I suppose)?

I've looked into using `propertize` and `buffer-display-table` to accomplish this, but every solution using those two has been a hack that ultimately fakes adding padding around the character.

An example of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
##|
| <-- I want this pipe to line up with the others
##|

Another example:
####|
௵|
####|
```

Manually adding padding around the variable width characters above is what I'd like to do. I don't know if it's possible though.

I already have a 'working' solution where I can add a space character after the other  char and then change the width of that space to line up the pipes. That isn't really 'padding' / 'margin' as it has the artifact of another character.

Comment: You might want to be a bit more specific about this. Perhaps an example of what you're starting with and what you want the result (even if just visual) to be.

Comment: Thanks, I added a little more detail. Let me know if that's better. I know what I want to accomplish in my head, but I don't know how to ask the right questions.

Comment: Yes, thanks. [(elisp) Specified Space](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Specified-Space.html) (e.g. `:align-to`) might offer some help with this (maybe, maybe not).

Comment: I think that would work, but it would still require me to add a space character (as that property only applies to spaces), which I'm hoping I don't have to do.